# Python subprocess module: what the code does?

Tags: python, shell, subprocess

What this piece of code is doing?

```
        with open(temp_path) as f:
            command = "xdg-open"
            subprocess.Popen(
                ["im=$(cat);" + command + " $im; rm -f $im"], shell=True, stdin=f
            )
```

I'm confused with the subprocess part...
What the shell script does?

Comment: Looks like it is executing some shell [commands](https://linux.die.net/man/1/xdg-open) (three commands in total) on some file name, including removing the file?

Comment: Yes, that is true, the question is what this shell command is doing.

Comment: That seems more like a shell question, not a Python question.

Comment: Well, it is shell + Python, and ideally I would like to get a complete overview of shell and Python interaction. The most confusing part for me is shell part.

Comment: It's _badly written_ shell. I don't recommend using it at all.

Comment: Well, it is coming from a well known Python library. :D

Comment: More broadly: to be on-topic here, "please explain this code" questions need to be narrow and specific. Tell us what you already do and don't understand.

Comment: Nobody said people who write well-known Python libraries are competent at writing secure, well-written shell. This particular author is clearly not.

Comment: 1) In the code above the shell command is executed from the Python script;

Comment: ...that said, while it's badly written, it shouldn't be that hard to understand. Do you know what `im=$(cat)` does? Do you know what `xdg-open $im` does? Do you understand what `rm -f $im` does? Explain the exact place you're stuck trying to understand it yourself.

Comment: (mind, `xdg-open $im` does extra things you probably don't want in addition to the behavior you probably _do_ want: it uses string-splitting to break the contents of `im` into multiple "words", and expands each word as a glob, replacing it with a list of filenames on disk should there be any names matching that expression. This presence of undesired side effects -- potentially security-impacting ones -- is part of why I assert that this code really shouldn't be used).

Comment: [How to handle "explain how this ${code dump} works" questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253894/how-to-handle-explain-how-this-code-dump-works-questions)

Answer (score 3):

```
im=$(cat)
```

uses `cat` to read the standard input, and assigns the result to the variable `im`. Since you use `stdin=f`, that reads the contents of `temp_path`.

```
command + " $im;`
```

executes the command `xdg-open` with `$im` as its argument. So this uses the contents of the file as the argument to `xdg-open`, which opens the file in its default application. Since the argument should be a filename, this implies that `temp_path` contains a filename.

```
rm -f $im
```

deletes the file that was opened.

This seems like a silly way to do this. A better way to write it would be:

```
with open(temp_path) as f:
    filename = f.read().strip()
command = "xdg-open"
subprocess.Popen([command, filename])
os.remove(filename)
```

Although I haven't seen the rest of the script, I suspect the temp path is also unnecessary when doing it this way -- it seems like it was just using that as a way to get the filename into the shell variable.

Comment: Mind, there's a race condition here: How do we know `xdg-open` has finished starting up and opening the file before the `os.remove()` runs? -- that's probably _why_ the original code is having the subshell do the `rm`.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy this is a part of the problem with this script. :)

Comment: @Barmar Thanks a lot!

Comment: @CharlesDuffy True, the script treats `xdg-open` as a synchronous command. This doesn't fix the problem, it just implements the original bug more cleanly.

Comment: At least this version doesn't have the splitting/globbing bug.

Comment: @Barmar One more question: Isn't the command "rm -f $im" redundant ? (The $im is not referring the file itself, it just holds the content of the file.)

Comment: It holds the contents of `temp_file`, which is the name of the file to open with xdg-open.